# using progress bar in loading a view or showing a page

Tags: javascript, user-interface, templates, progress-bar

I know this question is not about code or algorithm but i really just want to know so please understand.Anyone knows what plugin or what is the name of the feature on the screenshot.  I wanted to know what do you call that thing when you use like a progress bar to load pages and then use next and back to navigate instead. I wonder if there is existing sample we can use instaed of creating from scratch. Is that a progress bar?. Thank you. May i know the term ? what is the right name to that?

## url

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YvqT.jpg

[image]

Comment: This component is usually called a `Stepper` [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)

Comment: Thank you , can you recommend stepper for angular 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called multiple step form. A basic example can be found at: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Hope it helps